# CodeIgniter URL First Parameter indicating company

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm new to CodeIgniter, and I'm making a website for multi-company platform.

I understand the url now use the first parameter indicating controller and the second parameter indicating method. But what if I want to shift this rule?

I want it be https://www.url.com/companyName/controllerName/methodName, so the page can show logo and company related information.

How can I make this happen?

Edit 1:
ALL companyName, controllerName and methodName are variables.
Same set of controllers and methods applies to all companies.
It's like I'm always having a company variable at the beginning of url variable set

Answer (score 1):

Go to your **application/Config** folder and open the `route.php` and place the code snippet

```
$route['compnayName/controllerName/methodName'] = 'controllerName/methodName';
```

Read more here [CodeigniterRouting](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Comment: But companyName is a variable, and I want all my controller apply this rule. I have this list them all?

Comment: create a folder inside a controllers and place all your controllers inside it

Answer (score 1):

i think, you should use folder of company in `controller` folder, there you can add multiple controllers, that would not need to add each urls in `route.php`

If you have only single url to change with prefix company then you can use route.php otherwise sub folder would be good for multiple url's

LIKE this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1 : Make changes in config/route.php

```
$route['(:any)/controllerName/methodName'] = 'controllerName/methodName/$1';
```

2: Pass company_name / company_id as parameter in method and fetch all relavent details.